# jupyter using wrong sklearn

Tags: python, jupyter

I am using jupyter lab (via conda), and I am using `sklearn` in my code. I figured out I had an older version of `sklearn` in my virtual environment (0.19.1) so I updated it (`conda update scikit-learn`) and I got version 0.20.2.

The problem is that jupyter is still loading the previous version:
if I open the pytho REPL from the terminal and type

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
```

I get '0.20.2', but if I do the same in a cell of my notebook (started inside the same virtual environment), I get '0.19.1'.

How is this possible? Any hints on how to solve this?

Thanks!
Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a friend I got what is the underlying problem and found the solution. In few words the problem is that jupyter is based on a kernel that is not made out of the installations I have in my virtual environment. I have to create a kernel based on the virtual env.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython) is how to create a kernel.